# 'This' conflicts in angular and Jquery

Tags: jquery, angular, angularjs

I am trying to migrate a angularjs application into angular. The old application had jquery functionalites. I tried using the same. Issue with 'this' element.

When loading in angular, angular takes 'this' element has its component one and jquery 'this' element doesnt show up.

[image]

Appreciate any help!!!

Comment: In Angular you should not use jquery AT ALL. Angular has its own ways of selecting elements and manipulating the DOM. For your specific use case, you could either just use [ngClass] in your template to apply the styles you want, or you could use the Renderer2 class. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: @MichaelRentmeister - I agree using jquery in angular is not advisable. As i told,i am migrating an angularjs project where everything is wriiten in jquery. I wanted to use the same. I tried calling jquery dom in ngoninit and it is working as expected. Just that 'this' operator is common for angular and jquery. It gets mixed up. Any idea on it??

Comment: I understand that you're converting it, but if you're going to convert it then you should do it the supported Angular way. You will run into many other problems if you go down the path you're following.

Comment: problem is the arrow function combined with this. so use `e.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your arrow function in `click` by `function`.

using `this` inside arrow functions body will not create a new lexical context , hence your result.

Inside jQuery methods, such as click you need to use functions expressions that will allow the lexical context `this` to be bound to the current dom element.

Important reading about `this`, http://perfectionkills.com/know-thy-reference, spec about arrow functions and their pitfalls can be useful too.

Comment: This is the correct answer, pun intended. I still highly advise against the use of jquery though.